# Sending Push Notifications to Users Who Didn't Login

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification

We're on the test stage of our Mobile Push implementation. We are using setContactKey and Delay Registration Until Contact Key is Set method, and this way, all of our contact's devices are having contact key related to them.

But the thing is, we'ld also like to send push notifications to our customers who didn't login. Without login, I believe that the device will not have a contact key, and Marketing Cloud will delay the registration.

We are using Salesforce ID as Contact Key, which starts with 0034J0, so I've created a filtered list to see the devices without login(Contact key not contains 0034j0 and device id is not null), but I'm not able to see the devices.

Has anyone faced this issue before? How can we manage to send push notifications to users that did not login, just opened our app without login?

Answer (score 3):

If you have delayed registration until a Contact Key is set then what would the Marketing Cloud send to?  The registration is required to get the push token provided by Apple/Google sent up to the Marketing Cloud servers and propagated through to the Contact.

If you need to send push notifications to an anonymous or unknown user then you need to remove the delay in registration setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bill. Without delaying, how can we ensure that newly registered customers device's will have the right contact key? I mean, after 1 day of user creation, we receive user information on Service Cloud(from the customer's database) and after than the contact is having a contact key. We've found this method to guarantee that the device has the correct contact key. But now we'll be unable to send push to customers without login.

Comment: If the SDK does not set a Contact Key then the Marketing Cloud servers will assign a random GUID.  The Device ID and Push Token are registered and can be sent to.  Once you have a Contact Key, you simply set it in the SDK and the device will be migrated to the Contact.